# How to set DTO's value (object of entity class) to Generic list<entity class> using spring Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, data-transfer-objects

Please help me to resolve this issue which i am getting when using DTO's to pass values from DAO to Service layer. This is my DAO class.

```
@Repository
public class ProductDaoImpl implements ProductDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    private ProductDTO productDTO;
    //ProductDTO productDTO=new ProductDTO();

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public ProductDTO getAllProduct(){
        //public  List<Product_Catalog> getAllProduct(){ 
             //return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery("findAllProduct").list();


            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
                Query query=(Query) session.getNamedQuery("findAllProduct");
               // query.setInteger("productCatalogId", id);
               List<Product_Catalog> product=query.list();

               for (Iterator iterator = product.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                   Product_Catalog products = (Product_Catalog) iterator.next();
                   productDTO.setMaxPrice(products.getMaxPrice());
                   productDTO.setMinPrice(products.getMinPrice());
                   System.out.println("Max Price " + products.getMaxPrice());
                   System.out.println("Max Price " + productDTO.getMaxPrice());

               }

            return productDTO;
}
}
```

DTO class:

```
 public class ProductDTO implements java.io.Serializable {

         private int pincode;
         private int productCatalogId ;
         private Requirement_type requirementTypeId ;
         private Boolean isActive ;
         private Boolean isRequesterProduct ;
         private float maxPrice ;
         private float minPrice;
//getter ,setter 
}
```

ServiceImpl class:-

```
 @Service
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

    @Autowired
    private ProductDAO productDAO;

    List<Product_Catalog> product=new ArrayList<Product_Catalog>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public  List<Product_Catalog> getAllProduct(){ 

        ProductDTO productDTO= productDAO.getAllProduct();

            /*product.addAll(productDTO.getMaxPrice());
            product.addAll(0, Collection<Product_Catalog>c);
            product.add(productDTO.getMinPrice());*/



        // return productDAO.getAllProduct();
        return product;
    }
}
```

Controller class:-

```
@Controller
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

     @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String listProducts(ModelMap map)
        {
            map.addAttribute("product", new Product_Catalog());
            map.addAttribute("productList", productService.getAllProduct());

            return "productList";
        }
}
```

Entity class:-

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
    name = "findAllProduct",
   query = "from Product_Catalog"

    )
})

@Entity
public class Product_Catalog extends baseEntity.Entity {
    @Id
    @Column(name="Product_Catalog_Id")
    private int productCatalogId ;


}
```

jsp:-

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring 3 Hibernate integration </title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Product List</h2>


<h3>Products</h3>
<c:if  test="${!empty productList}">
<table class="data">
<tr>
    <!-- <th>Product_Catalog_Id</th> -->
    <!-- <th>Requirement_Type_Id</th> -->
    <th>Max Price</th>
    <th>Min_Price</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${productList}" var="product">
    <tr>

        <%-- <td>${product.productCatalogId}</td> --%>
        <%-- <td>${product.requirementTypeId}</td> --%>
        <td>${product.maxPrice}</td>
        <td>${product.minPrice}</td>
       <%--  <td><a href="delete/${prd.id}">delete</a></td> --%>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
</c:if>

</body>
</html>
```

My code was running fine with out using DTO, but i am getting issue when getting the value from DTO in service class. please suggest me how to set values in from dto to list to display list on jsp page. stack trace below:-

```
15:05:44,073 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Max Price 20000.0

15:05:44,073 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Max Price 20000.0

15:05:44,073 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Max Price 50000.0

15:05:44,073 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Max Price 50000.0

15:05:44,619 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/usermanagement].[jsp]] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'java.lang.Float' does not have the property 'maxPrice'.
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getBeanProperty(BeanELResolver.java:661) [jboss-el-api_2.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:290) [jboss-el-api_2.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:175) [jboss-el-api_2.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:134) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:187) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:935) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.productList_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(productList_jsp.java:158)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.productList_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f0(productList_jsp.java:116)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.productList_jsp._jspService(productList_jsp.java:76)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:734) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:541) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:479) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:407) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238) [spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264) [spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208) [spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992) [spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939) [spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) [spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936) [spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827) [spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812) [spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:139) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.NamingValve.invoke(NamingValve.java:57) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:154) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:667) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:952) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_43]
```

Comment: ProductDTO is a simple POJO why do you autowire it ?
You should simply instantiate it with the new operator inside the ProductDaoImpl.getAllProduct() method.

Answer (score 0):

your piece of code `@Autowired private ProductDAO productDAO;` is a disaster in web application, how can you guarantee thread safety for such an autowired field. Correct way would be to instantiate ProductDTO using new operator and simply return it.

The reason for error may be that your Product_Catalog class seems to have no setters and getters.

Comment: chill :) Spring to the rescue! I bet spring guarantees thread safety.

Comment: Well, I do not agree. By default all beans are singleton, how can it guarantee thread safety.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your code fails is here:

```
 product.addAll(0, Collection<Product_Catalog>c);
 product.add(productDTO.getMinPrice());
```

You commented this code, but what you're trying to do is to insert a `Float` into product list. JSP gets the `Float` from the list and tries to invoke `Float.getMinPrice().`

To avoid this put products into the `List`.